# Tensorflow runtime dictionary lookup, hendling output from tf.parse_single_sequence_example

Tags: python, dictionary, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow parse_single_sequence_example for decoding the record_string from TFRecordReader. It returns two dicts, one for context_features and other for sequence_features.

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer('temp.text', num_epochs=1, shuffle=True)
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
key, record_string = reader.read(filename_queue)
context_features={
    "output":tf.FixedLenFeature([],tf.int64)
    }
sequence_features={
    "input_sequence":tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([5,],tf.float32)
    }   
context_parsed, sequence_parsed = tf.parse_single_sequence_example(serialized=record_string,context_features=context_features,sequence_features=sequence_features)
```

context_parsed and sequence_parsed are both dictionaries. How do I get the tensor object associated with the keys. If I do the following fetch operation

```
 with tf.Session() as sess:
     a=sess.run([context_parsed],feed_dict=None)
```

It fails and understandably so.

```
Fetch argument {'output': <tf.Tensor 'ParseSingleSequenceExample/ParseSingleSequenceExample:1' shape=() dtype=int64>} of {'output': <tf.Tensor 'ParseSingleSequenceExample/ParseSingleSequenceExample:1' shape=() dtype=int64>} has invalid type <class 'dict'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a dict into a Tensor or Operation.)
```

How do I fetch the context_parsed['output'] tensor? How do I feed that tensor to some placeholder in my graph?

```
out=context_parsed['output']
```

I add the above line and try to fetch it but it does not work and the terminal just gets stuck in ipython.

```
 with tf.Session() as sess:
     a=sess.run(out,feed_dict=None)
```

I am also adding the output of tf.contrib.learn.run_n

```
In [13]: context = tf.contrib.learn.run_n(context_parsed, n=1, feed_dict=None)
In [14]: context[0]
Out[14]: {'length': 6, 'output': 4}
In [15]: context = tf.contrib.learn.run_n(out, n=1, feed_dict=None)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-e5d7d977676f> in <module>()
```

----> 1 context = tf.contrib.learn.run_n(out, n=1, feed_dict=None)

```
/home/ankgoyal/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-    packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/graph_actions.py in   run_n(output_dict, feed_dict, restore_checkpoint_path, n)
    553       output_dict=output_dict,
    554       feed_dicts=itertools.repeat(feed_dict, n),
--> 555       restore_checkpoint_path=restore_checkpoint_path)
    556 
    557 

/home/ankgoyal/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/graph_actions.py in run_feeds(output_dict, feed_dicts, restore_checkpoint_path)
    579     ValueError: if `output_dict` or `feed_dicts` is None or empty.
    580   """
    --> 581   if not output_dict:
    582     raise ValueError('output_dict is invalid: %s.' % output_dict)
    583   if not feed_dicts:

/home/ankgoyal/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in __bool__(self)
    513       `TypeError`.
    514     """
--> 515     raise TypeError("Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. "
    516                     "Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a "
    517                     "tensor is defined, and use the logical TensorFlow ops "

TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use the logical TensorFlow ops to test the value of a tensor.
```

**How do I fetch the context_parsed['output'] tensor? How do I feed that tensor to some placeholder in my graph?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the mistake I was doing. Actually, I didn't start the new thread for TFReader() and because of it, the terminal gets hanged up.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    print(sess.run(context_parsed['length']))
    coord.join(threads)
```

The output is printed as 6